# Python: list inside a list index out of range error

Tags: python, list, indexing, range

I'm getting an error when trying to append values to a list inside of a list. What am I doing wrong?

```
xRange = 4
yRange = 3
baseList = []
values = []
count = 0

#make a list of 100 values
for i in range(100):
    values.append(i)

#add 4 lists to base list
for x in range(xRange):
    baseList.append([])
#at this point i have [[], [], [], []]

#add 3 values to all 4 lists
    for x in range(xRange):
        for y in range(yRange):
            baseList[x][y].append(values[count])
            count += 1

print baseList

#the result i'm expecting is:
#[[0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8], [9,10,11]]
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
    baseList[x][y].append(values[count])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: As a side note, you can make a list of `n` empty lists like so: `baseList = [[]] * n`. No need for an explicit loop.

Comment: @Iguananaut - That will create multiple references to the same list, so when you modify one, all of them are affected. It's a common mistake.

Comment: Ah, definitely. How embarrassing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't index into an empty list. You should call `append` on the list itself.

Change this:

```
baseList[x][y].append(values[count])
```

To this:

```
baseList[x].append(values[count])
```

Result:

```
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]]
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/vaFhoa)

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in range(xRange):
    baseList.append([])
# at this point i have [[], [], [], []]
```

Right, `baseList = [[], [], [], []]`. As such, accessing `baseList[0][0]` will fail as the first sublist has no elements.

Btw. you can get the wanted list a lot easier using some [itertools](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) and [recipes](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

```
>>> x = 4
>>> y = 3
>>> list(itertools.islice(zip(*([itertools.count()] * y)), x))
[(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8), (9, 10, 11)]
```

This is basically an x-*take* of an y-*grouper* of an indefinite *count* starting at 0.